# Delphi 2009 - Set default property values in custom delphi components

Tags: delphi, properties, components, custom-component

This should be very simple but I can't find the exact answer I want. I have a custom delphi control based on TSpeedButton. I want the Caption Property of the SpeedButton to always be 'Comments' but I don't want to set it at run-time I want to set it in the component itself so that when I place it on my form it's already populated with this text. I also want to set the height and width of the button but I imagine the method for doing this will be the same as for setting the caption.

For the sake of completeness, here is the component code:

```
unit CustomSpeedButton;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Controls, Buttons;

type
  TCustomSpeedButton = class(TSpeedButton)
  private
    FCommentText: string;
    FCommentTitle: string;

    procedure SetCommentText(const Value: string);
    procedure SetCommentTitle(const Value: string);

    { Private declarations }
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }

  published
    { Published declarations }
    property CommentTitle: string read FCommentTitle write SetCommentTitle;
    property CommentText: string read FCommentText write SetCommentText;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Standard', [TCustomSpeedButton]);
end;

{ TCustomSpeedButton }

procedure TCustomSpeedButton.SetCommentText(const Value: string);
begin
  FCommentText := Value;
end;

procedure TCustomSpeedButton.SetCommentTitle(const Value: string);
begin
  FCommentTitle := Value;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the *default* caption to be "Comments," or do you mean that you want the caption to *always* be "Comments," no matter what the developer changes it to later?

Comment: The default caption to be 'Comments'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you wanted the Caption property to be done properly, Mason's answer is not going to work because he missed the 'csSetCaption' thing, and his suggestion about 'default' will not work either because both the Caption and your properties are string types.

Below are the units as you want them.

The behaviour is as follows:

1. intially the value of the Caption property will be 'Comments'
2. users can override that at design time by setting a new value

(If you do not want 2., then you need to assign the Caption property in an overrided Loaded method like Ken mentioned; however, it was not clear from your question if you wanted that. If you do, then please rephrase your question.)

This is how the code works.

For string properties, you cannot hint the streaming system of any **default**.
But you can set an initial value for design time in the constructor: **Caption := DefaultCustomSpeedButtonCaption;**

For the Caption property, you must also disable the default assignment of the Caption property (otherwise your component would be automatically get a caption like 'CustomSpeedButton1').
This line does that for you: **ControlStyle := ControlStyle - [csSetCaption];**

Finally it is good practice to split your component registration into a separate unit.
That allows you to have a design-time package that registers your components in the IDE and a run-time package (or no package at all) for using your components in your applications.

If you have a component icon, then you load that in the registration unit as well (since it is only needed at design time).

Ray Konopka has written an excellent book on component writing which is still very valid: [Developing Custom Delphi 3 Components](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1576101126)
Like many good Delphi books, it is out of print, but you can [order a PDF copy on his site](http://www.raize.com/DevTools/Ordering/Pricing.asp).

I'm not sure what your CommentTitle and CommentText properties are for, so I have kept them in the source below.

*Listing 1: actual component*

```
unit CustomSpeedButtonUnit;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Controls, Buttons;

const
  DefaultCustomSpeedButtonCaption = 'Comments';

type
  TCustomCustomSpeedButton = class(TSpeedButton)
  strict private
    FCommentText: string;
    FCommentTitle: string;
  strict protected
    procedure SetCommentText(const Value: string); virtual;
    procedure SetCommentTitle(const Value: string); virtual;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property CommentTitle: string read FCommentTitle write SetCommentTitle;
    property CommentText: string read FCommentText write SetCommentText;
  end;

  TCustomSpeedButton = class(TCustomCustomSpeedButton)
  published
// note you cannot use 'default' for string types; 'default' is only valid for ordinal ordinal, pointer or small set type
// [DCC Error] CustomSpeedButtonUnit.pas(29): E2146 Default values must be of ordinal, pointer or small set type
//    property Caption default DefaultCustomSpeedButtonCaption;
    property CommentTitle;
    property CommentText;
  end;

implementation

constructor TCustomCustomSpeedButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Caption := DefaultCustomSpeedButtonCaption;
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle - [csSetCaption];
end;

destructor TCustomCustomSpeedButton.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TCustomCustomSpeedButton.SetCommentText(const Value: string);
begin
  FCommentText := Value;
end;

procedure TCustomCustomSpeedButton.SetCommentTitle(const Value: string);
begin
  FCommentTitle := Value;
end;

end.
```

*Listing 2: component registration*

```
unit CustomSpeedButtonRegistrationUnit;

interface

procedure Register;

implementation

uses
  CustomSpeedButtonUnit;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Standard', [TCustomSpeedButton]);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. After several false starts I came to the conclusion I was just asking for too much and ended up just selecting all the buttons after pasting them to the page and altering their characteristics as a 'batch'. The complete listing you give above though shows that all is not lost so I appreciate your input. Also, I actually own a copy of that book on Delphi 3 components (D3 was my first exposure to Delphi back around '98) .. I never got around to reading it but will do so now!

Comment: Hm, interesting. I started a new component to try it your way and after creating the component registration unit and then saving and attempting to switch to another project the IDE kicked me out and wont restart now .. only thing I did differently was modify the register procedure to just say 'begin register; end;' because registercomponents kept throwing an error about it being unrecognized. Must be a way to clear the IDE cache somehow ..

Comment: Ooops - if you do a "procedure Register; begin Register; end;" then you get an infinite loop. And when you put such a loop in a design-time package that gets loaded in the IDE, then the IDE will hang.

The best solution for that is to close the Delphi IDE, find the component package .bpl that you got the infinite loop into, then delete that .bpl file, then start the Delphi IDE.

Hope that helps. If not, drop me an email (almost anything at pluimers dot com will get to me, but the easiest is to use my first name). I can do a TeamViewer session with you to resolve it.

Good luch!

--jeroen

Comment: Three years later but still relevant: the above does not work in the case where we want the user to be able to override the default property with a blank string. There does not seem to be a way to use stored/default/nodefault on a string property so there is no way to tell the streaming system that a string property's default value is something non-blank. If we set a string property to blank then it is not stored in the stream, and so whatever we set in the constructor will come back again. To avoid this I set default values in an event fired from the designer after the control is dropped.

Comment: @Etherman care to write an answer with your solution? It sounds very valuable and interesting. Would definitely +1 it.

Comment: Sorry, I have no solution as yet for the standard IDE. My application has a clone of the Delphi form designer so I am able to insert my own event code when I drop a new control onto a form. Perhaps there is a similar event or interface that can be used with TControl that is triggered by the Delphi IDE, if I find it I will put an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the original values in the component's constructor.

EDIT:  You'll also want to put add `ControlStyle := ControlStyle - [csSetCaption];` to the constructor.

Comment: @Mason: That won't always work. The constructor is called, and then properties are set as the DFM is streamed in. What you do in the constructor can be replaced by content in the DFM.

Comment: Yes, and that's the expected and desired behavior.  If the user enters something in a property, saves, reloads, and what they saved has been changed, they're going to be annoyed.

Comment: I've read that it should be done in the constructor before and I swear I used to know where that was but now I'm pulling my hair out trying to find it!

Comment: It's not there because you haven't written it yet.  Declare a constructor on the class that looks like this:  `constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;`  Have it call the inherited constructor and then set up default values.

Comment: Hehe, apparently I need to go find me a 'Delphi for Dummies' or some such reference! That was the info I needed, Mason. Thanks!

Comment: -1: You cannot use 'default' for string type properties; you also need to add "ControlStyle := ControlStyle - [csSetCaption];" to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

@Etherman: In case you want to have a string property with default value AND you want to save it to DFM - even if it is BLANK - you have to do it yourself. Fortunately, Delphi gives you methods to do that. Take a look at this code:

```
type
  TMyComp = class(TControl)
  private
    FMyStringProperty: string;
    procedure WriteMyStringProperty(Writer: TWriter);
    procedure DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);  override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property MyStringProperty: string read FMyStringProperty write FMyStringProperty stored False;
  end;


implementation


constructor TMyComp.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FMyStringProperty := 'my default value';
end;

procedure TMyComp.WriteMyStringProperty(Writer: TWriter);
begin
  Writer.WriteString(FMyStringProperty);
end;

procedure TMyComp.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
begin
  inherited DefineProperties(Filer);
  Filer.DefineProperty('MyStringProperty', nil, WriteMyStringProperty, True);
end;
```